# Java: How to start Client or Server, depending on if Server is already up?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

i coded a game with an playing field represented in Arrays. I now implemented 2 classes, called Client and Server, Client has a "send" Button. The Server has a textarea, where the data send, in my case an Array Object, is displayed as a string <-both for testing right now. Sending Data works fine and i want to connect my game with it. Currently this works only one way right now Client->Server, i will implement 2 way connection later.

My problem : I want the first player to connect act as a host/server and therefore initialize the server, if the game is started. If a second person starts the game on his pc afterwards, he needs to conect as a client to the already running server. How do i check if server is already running and therefore create a client instance for the second player?

Thanks in Advance!

My code for Client:

```
package connect4;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ClientTest {

    static protected ObjectOutputStream myoutput;


     public static void main(String[] args) {

      ClientTest client = new ClientTest();

          //test
       }



public ClientTest() {
    System.out.println("Client is connected");
    Window window1=new Window();

        window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
class Window extends JFrame{

    public Window(){

        setBounds(600,300,280,350);

        WindowClient winClient=new WindowClient();

        add(winClient);

        setVisible(true);
        }   

}

class WindowClient extends JPanel{

    public WindowClient(){

        JLabel text=new JLabel("CLIENT");

        add(text);





        mybutton=new JButton("Send");

        SendText textfield= new SendText();

        mybutton.addActionListener(textfield);

        add(mybutton);  

    }

private class SendText implements ActionListener{



        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //System.out.println(campo1.getText());
            try {
                Socket mysocket=new Socket("localhost",9999);
                System.out.println("Data was sent..");
                ObjectOutputStream myoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mysocket.getOutputStream());   

                myoutput.writeObject(GridTest.gamefield);

                myoutput.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            }// meine IP und eine freie Port
        }
    }


        //asd

private JTextField field1;

private JButton mybutton;

}}
```

My code for Server:

```
package connect4;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerTest  {
    private static char [][] spot = new char [6][7];
    static boolean connected;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ServerTest server = new ServerTest();

    }   



public ServerTest() {
    WindowServer mywindow=new WindowServer();

    mywindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
class WindowServer extends JFrame implements Runnable  {

    public WindowServer(){

        setBounds(1200,300,280,350);                

        JPanel newpanel= new JPanel();

        newpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textarea=new JTextArea();

        newpanel.add(textarea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(newpanel);

        setVisible(true);

        Thread mythread = new Thread(this);

        mythread.start();

        }

    private JTextArea textarea;



    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(9999);//port öfnnen listen und Verbindungen akzeptieren

            while(true) {
            Socket mysocket= server.accept();

            ObjectInputStream myinput=new ObjectInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());

            Object mymessage = myinput.readObject();

            textarea.append("\n" + mymessage);
            System.out.println(mymessage);
            System.out.println("Data recieved...");
            mysocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Try to start the server. If you get a bind exception, start the client. Don't do it the other way round, as there is a timing window problem that way.

Comment: how do i start server or client, depending which one is already up. the game is one single file, so there needs to be an if statement of some sort checking wether connect as client or start a server, if there is no server

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code:

```
class ServerClient {
    try {
        connect(remoteServerCredentials);
    } catch (java.io.SocketException exception) {
        //  print failed to connect Starting up as server
        //  Start up the Server()
    }
}
```

Comment: Timing window problem here. If you start two clients in quick succession both can get the connect exceptions and then both will try to start the server, and then you have to deal with a second failure mode. You should try to start the server unconditionally, and then only start the client if that failed. No timing window that way.

Comment: how do i check if Server is running?